# iPhone Client/Server Application without Mac Server

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on a client/server application and considering the iPhone platform for my next client. My only issue is that my server currently only runs on Windows. Will Apple even consider approving my app without having a Mac server available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't care what software your server is running on. As long as the iPhone client app meets their guidelines you should be fine.

I'm not sure what sort of app you're writing, but consider some of the apps in the store already: IM applications that interface with IRC, AIM, Facebook, Twitter etc. These servers almost certainly aren't Macs.

Comment: I'm not sure how the process works 100%, would I give them some kind of demo account to login with while verifying?

Comment: I suppose that would be up to you to decide. If the bulk of your application content is behind a login wall, perhaps.

I would ask an Apple rep directly about these sorts of questions. You could try emailing them at appreview@apple.com.